# Creating a Y / N flag if a date in a column is within the last 12 months based on the max date of a column

Tags: date, filter, powerbi

I am trying to create a column in my power BI report that I can use as the basis for a filter.

My query is called "Power Bi - Trending Data". The column with the date I am interested in is called "Last Day of the Month (Record Date)"

What I would like to do is a a Y / N flag in a column to say if a date in the "Last Day of the Month (Record Date) is in the last 12 months, based on the maximum date that is in this "Last Day of the Month (Record Date)" column.

Something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qor4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a calculated column, you need something like this, depending on how you want to handle the actual calculation of "what is 1 year looking back":

```
Is Within 12 Months of Max = 
VAR _max = MAX ( 'Table'[Last Day of the Month (Record Date)] )
VAR _limit = DATE ( YEAR ( _max ) - 1 , MONTH ( _max ) , DAY ( _max ) )
RETURN
IF ( 
    [Last Day of the Month (Record Date)] > _limit, 
    1,
    0
)
```

Comment: That's great, that's done the trick. Thank you.